# Delete empty rows on Column A in excel 2007

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I have the following piece of code that takes in the empty rows from Column A and then deletes the entire row. I could not use the Special--> Blanks --> Delete Sheet Rows feature on 2010 because 2007 has an upper bound of approximately 8000 non contiguous rows. This code is super slow on some older machines and takes about 40 minutes to finish (but does the job). Is there any faster alternative to this?

```
 Private Sub Del_rows()
    Dim r1 As Range, xlCalc As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrShts As Variant
    With Application
        xlCalc = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    arrShts = VBA.Array("Sheet1")  'add additional sheets as required
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrShts)
        With Sheets(arrShts(i))
            For j = .UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -8000
                If j - 7999 < 2 Then
                    .Range("A2:A" & j).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                Else
                    .Range("A" & j, "A" & j - 7999).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            Next j
        End With
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code takes under a second on 100,000 rows (record the actions for the fuller code if needed):

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Columns(1).Insert xlToRight
Columns(1).FillLeft
Columns(1).Replace "*", 1
Cells.Sort Cells(1, 1)
Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
Columns(1).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Would this work on Excel 2007? I ask because 2007 has a limitation of approx 8000 non contiguous rows.

Comment: Yes this code should work in all versions. It just sorts the sheet so that all rows can be deleted in a single block.

Comment: Wow. That works like a charm!! I will adapt this code in my spread sheet because there are some custom tags (unwanted text) in there which I will need to delete before I put in this code.

Answer (score 4):

Rajiv, Try this. This should be fast.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim delrange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1") '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheetname
        '~~> Get the last Row in Col A
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Len(Trim(.Range("A" & i).Value)) = 0 Then
                If delrange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delrange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delrange = Union(delrange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i

        If Not delrange Is Nothing Then delrange.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

You can also use Autofilter to delete the rows. This is pretty fast. I **haven't** tested both the examples for such huge rows :) Do let me know if you get any errors.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        With .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
          .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=""
          .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        '~~> Remove any filters
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: I did not get a chance to test this completely, but I from the run time, it looks like the first piece was about the same. I will definitely try this soon and report back on what I find. Thanks though!!

Comment: Actually on large numbers of rows I find the code posted in the question significantly faster than the first suggestion. I think the AutoFilter method will scale better but this is also liable to the ~8000 areas limit on Excel 2007 and earlier.